# FBProfilePictureView not filling the assigned space in the storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, facebook-ios-sdk

Well pretty straight forward.

FBProfilePictureView uses (by my knowing) all the UIImageView methods. Knowing this i tried to use AscpectToFit (first in the storyboard second in the code when the first one didn't work.

the i tried this:

```
   self.fb_background.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleToFill
```

This works only in height. I also tried resizing the frame this resulted in my images halfway down my page(instead of the top left

what am i doing wrong?

The problem is that my pictures width is not correct! its

Comment: I don't think FBProfilePictureView extends UIImageView. From the documentation it states that resizing frame may result in different size of image loaded. Give us a screenshot or explain better on what issue you are having and what you are trying to achieve https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/3.5/class/FBProfilePictureView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that FBProfilePictureView contains a UIImageView and does not expose it for you to modify it's properties.

It downloads a square image if `pictureCropping == FBProfilePictureCroppingSquare` otherwise it downloads a small, medium or large image depending on the width of the frame. But there is no way to control how this image is scaled to fill the FBProfilePictureView.

I created a [replacement view](https://github.com/combinatorial/DBFBProfilePictureView) which exposes the UIImageView through a read-only `imageView` property and therefore allows you to control its contentMode.

Comment: Thank you this is what i needed! Im struggling a lot with the Facebook SDK and this helped a lot!